# In the pronunciation of 잘할게, the 할 sounds likeㄱ+ㅏ+ㄹ, and 게 sounds like ㄲ + ㅔ, and I'm confused

Tags: pronunciation

This is the full sentence: 넌 아무 말 안 해 아 제발 내가 **잘할게**
I don't know any Korean, but just trying to pronounce. I hear "Chalgalkke" via Google Translate pronounce. The initial position makes the ㅈ sound like ㅊ because of light aspiration. However, I don't understand why the 할 sounds likeㄱ+ㅏ+ㄹ (gal), and 게 sounds like ㄲ + ㅔ (kke). I couldn't find the rules for these online. Anyone can shed some light?

Comment: It has no /g/ sound. “ㄹ” might sound /d/, /r/, or /l/ to English ears. So maybe that's why.

Comment: @КонстантинВан I'm studying Japanese and I think it's very similar to the Japanese "r" (らりるれろ）, which sounds like r/d/l, but over here, I heard "g" for some reason.

Comment: Right, good catch. IPA helps here. [Consonants in the ら-row make the voiced alveolar flap sound /ɾ/ right after a vowel.](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%AF%E8%8C%8E%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%81%8D%E9%9F%B3) And [so does a ㄹ initial that is not preceded by a ㄹ final.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_phonology) For the /g/-sounding ― no clue, sorry.

Comment: Can I ask what your native language is? @CreativiTimothy That likely influences your perception also of ㅎ vs ㄱ.

Comment: @Michaelyus English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard pronunciation for “잘할게” (Verb “잘하다” ＋ Ending conjugation **“-ᆯ게”**) is [잘할**께**], one of the possible transliterations of which is “Chalhalkke.” And the rule applied is *Tensation*, *Tensification* or *Unaspiration* (*경음화* (硬音化) or *된소리되기* in Korean).

> ## [*Korean language standard, Part Ⅱ (“Standard pronunciation”), §6 (“Tensation”)*](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000102), Clause 27.
>
> [image: The NIKL logo]
>
> ---
>
> “ㄱ,” “ㄷ,” “ㅂ,” “ㅅ,” and “ㅈ” right after the en-modifier conjugation “-ᆯ” or “-을” get tensed (unaspirated).
>
> 관형사형 ‘-(으)ᆯ’ 뒤에 연결되는 ‘ㄱ, ㄷ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅈ’은 된소리로 발음한다.
>
> - 할 것을[할**꺼**슬]
> - 갈 데가[갈**떼**가]
> - 할 바를[할**빠**를]
> - 할 수는[할**쑤**는]
> - 할 적에[할**쩌**게]
> - 갈 곳[갈**꼳**]
> - 할 도리[할**또**리]
> - 만날 사람[만날**싸**람]
>
> Exception: they're pronounced as lax sounds when pronouncing the two separately.
>
> 다만, 끊어서 말할 적에는 예사소리로 발음한다.
>
> ---
>
> [Addendum] The same goes for **conjugations beginning with “-ᆯ”** or “-을.”
>
> [붙임] ‘-(으)ᆯ’로 시작되는 어미의 경우에도 이에 준한다.
>
> - 할걸[할**껄**]
> - 할밖에[할**빠**께]
> - 할세라[할**쎄**라]
> - 할수록[할**쑤**록]
> - 할지라도[할**찌**라도]
> - 할지언정[할**찌**언정]
> - 할진대[할**찐**대]

---

### Helpful notes

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenseness
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortis_and_lenis

Comment: This is great! Do you know if there's a complete pronunciation rule list in English for Korean? If not, it's fine but helpful for beginners like me who mainly want to sing Korean.

Comment: @CreativiTimothy There have been quite a few books published on the "Sounds of Korean". Wikipedia's [Korean phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_phonology) page is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a word of the form (consonant + vowel +
consonant-a)(consonant-b + vowel + ...)

1) Here we have difficulty in pronouncing consonant-a so that we mix
a,b or strength b

For instance, 국밥(boiled rice served in soup), 할게 sounds like
국빱, 할께

And 잘할게 is 자+ㄹ할+케. (Here ㅎ is pronounced weakly so that
extremely speaking, it sounds like 자랄께, 자라깨 or 자랏깨)

2) Not changing case : 점박이 (dotted animal) is 점바기

Note that there is no change in ㅁㅂ and a change in ㄱo

Recall the order of consonant ㄱ ㄴ ㄷ ㄹ ㅁ ㅂ ㅅ o ㅈ ㅊ ㅋ ㅌ ㅍ
ㅎ

In my thought, there is short distance between ㅁ and ㅂ and a large
distance between ㄱ and o